# How to pass two parameters from view to controller but display only one in url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building an app in MVC 4 and I'm stuck on one thing.

I have a controller and action:

```
public ActionResult Details(string pattern, int id)
{
    Post post = repository.GetPostById(id);

    return View(post);
}
```

And in the view:

```
<div class="innerbody">
    @Model.Description @Html.ActionLink("Czytaj dalej...", "Details", new { id = Model.PostId, pattern = Model.ShortUrl})
</div>
```

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is that the url will be:

```
www.mysite.com/blog/pattern
```

Without `id`. 'pattern' is `ShortUrl` extracted from post title.

I've tried adding these different routes to RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Details",
    url: "{Controller}/{pattern}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Blog", action = "Details", pattern = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Details",
    url: "{Controller}/{pattern}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Blog", action = "Details", pattern = ""}
);
```

But it keeps throwing the error:

> *The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(System.String, Int32)' in 'MyBlog.Controllers.BlogController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.*

I think I can't catch this 'routing' thing... How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: How many routes do you have in your global.asax?

Comment: Routes are in separate file RouteConfig.cs and there is only default route at the moment. I try to add second.

Comment: Just try to place you default route below your new route. and let me know if its still giving problem.

Comment: Yup, that is what I tried first, but unfortunately it failed.

Comment: Set a default value for id like `int id = 0` Most databases start their index at 1 so 0 should be relatively safe.

Comment: So now I'm getting: sequence contains no elements from "Post post = repository.GetPostById(id);" cause it's passing zero to it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply do not want the `id` to appear in the URL but do want to send it to the action then the simplest thing to do would be to `POST` it, either with a form or ajax.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Blog", new { pattern = Model.ShortUrl }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostId)
}
```

OR

```
$.post(
    @Url.Action("Details", "Blog", new { pattern = Model.ShortUrl }),
    new { id: Model.PostId }
);
```

Either of your routes should be fine then, though there is no point in mentioning `id` in any of them if you don't intend on extracting it from the URL.

Admittedly it is odd to use a `POST` for a scenario that suits a `GET` but in a `GET` you can only send information via the URL, i.e route values and the querystring.  Using a `POST` allows you to send it in the form collection which is not seen in the URL obviously but MVC will examine its values for model binding which allows you to still obtain the `id` as an action method parameter.